# Finding position of html div in NodeList

Tags: javascript, html

the console log below returns a nodeList but I am not sure how to access locally to detect overlapping with *var a* Can the for loop be used inside the function detecting position? I am a bit lost.

```js
b = document.querySelectorAll('.enemy');
  a = document.getElementById('char');
  function overlaps(a, b) {
    for (let i = 0; i > b.length + 1; i++) {
      const rect2 = b.getBoundingClientRect();
      const rect1 = a.getBoundingClientRect();
      const isInHoriztonalBounds =
        rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width && rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x;
      const isInVerticalBounds =
        rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height && rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y;
      const isOverlapping = isInHoriztonalBounds && isInVerticalBounds;
      return isOverlapping;
    }
  }

  let timerId = setInterval(function () {
    if (overlaps(a, b)) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      console.log('overlaps');
    }
    obstaclePos -= 1;
    obstacle.style.left = obstaclePos + '%';
    obsprite.classList.add('faceleft');
    obsprite.classList.add('animation');
  }, 150);
  console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if elements `a` and `b` are overlapping by modifying your `overlaps` function as follows:

```
function overlaps(a, b) {
    const rect1 = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        const rect2 = b.item(i).getBoundingClientRect();
        const isInHoriztonalBounds =
            rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width && rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x;
        const isInVerticalBounds =
            rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height && rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y;
        const isOverlapping = isInHoriztonalBounds && isInVerticalBounds;
        if (isOverlapping) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Modifications made:

- taking `rect1` out of the for loop as it stays the same for each iteration
- replacing nodeList `b` in `rect2` with individual elements `b.item(i)`
- changing the return logic of the function to return `true` when the first overlap is found and `false` in case no overlap was found within the for loop